# How do I claim Canadian EI received while living in the US on my US taxes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, canada

I immigrated to the US from Canada last summer, and shortly thereafter started claiming Canadian Employment Insurance I was entitled to. Now, I'm filing both my US and Canadian taxes, but I'm not sure what to do with my EI earnings, since I was a US permanent resident while I was receiving the benefits.

The benefits were taxed in Canada (25%) before I received each payment. Do I claim this as foreign income, unemployment insurance or what on my 1040? Do I fill out a form 1116 to list the income as tax exempt/foreign tax credit? Do I need to fill out a form 2555?

I am filing jointly with my US citizen wife.

Comment: You are not generally eligible for EI while living abroad. To do so you must be available for work in Canada, which it does not sound like you are. What made you think you were eligible for EI?